Issues with BitBlt in MFC when scrolling: Not drawing newly visible regions
I'm working on implementing double buffering using a memory DC in an MFC project that utilizes CScrollView. My custom view class is derived from CScrollView.
However, I encounter an issue when scrolling down: the newly visible areas are not drawn.
I attempted to reset the viewport origin with memDC.SetViewportOrg(0, 0); but this did not resolve the issue. Moreover, the previously visible areas are redrawn incorrectly after scrolling — they do not align with the amount I've scrolled.
Surprisingly, I found a workaround that contradicts the official MSDN description of the BitBlt parameters.
Could someone help clarify why the observed behavior differs from the MSDN documentation? What might I be missing in handling scrolling and redrawing correctly in a CScrollView with double buffering?
Here's the code without all the miscellaneous bits:
void CMyScrollView::OnDraw(CDC* pDC)
{
    CDocument* pDoc = GetDocument();
    ASSERT_VALID(pDoc);
    if (!pDoc)
        return;

    CRect rect;
    GetClientRect(&rect);

    CDC memDC;
    memDC.CreateCompatibleDC(pDC);

    CBitmap bitmap;
    bitmap.CreateCompatibleBitmap(pDC, rect.Width(), rect.Height());
    CBitmap* pOldBitmap = memDC.SelectObject(&bitmap);

    // set the viewport origin to reflect the mouse scroll.
    CPoint scrollPos = GetDeviceScrollPosition();
    memDC.SetViewportOrg(-scrollPos.x, -scrollPos.y);

    // custom drawing function.
    myDrawingFunction(&memDC); 

    // reset the viewport origin.
    // memDC.SetViewportOrg(0, 0);

    pDC->BitBlt(0, 0, rect.Width(), rect.Height(), &memDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

    // This works, but seems quite hacky and it doesn't seem to match the MSDN description of the parameters.
    // pDC->BitBlt(0, 0, rect.Width()+scrollPos.x, rect.Height()+scrollPos.y, &memDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY)

    memDC.SelectObject(pOldBitmap);
}


What are the contradictions in the BitBlt() documentation exactly? I think its very accurate.

@ConstantineGeorgiou I'm saying that the code I tried (you can see it in my code which is commented out) does not match the doc.

I found other solutions and these seem legit, and figured out why my original hacky solution worked.
    // (In real code, we'd better check the return values of these functions.)

    // Coordinate modification.
    //  - Both below methods work in my device, but using logical units might be better 
    //    since `BitBlt` uses logical units.
    //    (BitBlt/GetScrollPosition/GetDeviceScrollPosition use logical/logical/device units, respectively.)
    //  - method 1.
    CPoint scrPos1 = GetScrollPosition();
    memDC.SetWindowOrg(scrPos1.x, scrPos1.y);
    //  - method 2.
    //CPoint scrPos2 = GetDeviceScrollPosition();
    //memDC.SetViewportOrg(-scrPos2.x, -scrPos2.y);


    // draw whatever eg. myDrawingFunction(&memDC); ...
    // then call BitBlt.


    // solution 1
    pDC->BitBlt(scrPos1.x, scrPos1.y, cliRect.Width(), cliRect.Height(), &memDC, scrPos1.x, scrPos1.y, SRCCOPY);
    
    // solution 2_1 (when using `SetViewportOrg`)
    //  However, I'm not sure this would work in general, because
    //  on my device now, the units of the `GetScrollPosition` and `GetDeviceScrollPosition` return values ​​seem to be the same.
    memDC.SetViewportOrg(0, 0);
    pDC->BitBlt(scrPos2.x, scrPos2.y, cliRect.Width(), cliRect.Height(), &memDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
    
    // solution 2_2 (when using `SetWindowOrg`)
    memDC.SetWindowOrg(0, 0);
    pDC->BitBlt(scrPos1.x, scrPos1.y, cliRect.Width(), cliRect.Height(), &memDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

Also, if you want, you can use CDC::GetClipBox instead of CWnd::GetClientRect
    // solution 3 (using CDC::GetClipBox instead of CWnd::GetClientRect)
    //  - `GetClipBox` just shifts the coordinates of the CRect as scroll amount, 
    //    so this is the same as solution 1.
    CRect clipRect;
    pDC->GetClipBox(&clipRect);
    // ...create bitmap with clipRect's Width() and Height() and then draw whatever eg. myDrawingFunction(&memDC); ...
    // then call BitBlt.
    pDC->BitBlt(clipRect.left, clipRect.top, clipRect.Width(), clipRect.Height(), &memDC, clipRect.left, clipRect.top, SRCCOPY);

Now we can understand why my original (hacky) solution worked, but I think it's not using the BitBlt function as its intention. So I'm thinking to use one of the above solutions.

Added:
Just for future reference, since this is an answer to myself)
My original question and the answer(example codes right above) were about drawing on the bitmap whose size is just the same as the visible client area. So, the bitmap has to be redrawn whenever the mouse scrolling happens.
To fix this, one solution would be drawing a larger area (eg. entire scrollable area) on the bitmap once, and just outputting only the visible part of it when mouse scrolls.
Right now I don't have time to do this, but in the future, if I wanna make this efficient, I should consider separating custom drawing function (which actually draws on the in-memory bitmap - eg. calling LineTo many times) from the OnDraw since OnDraw is called many times here and there in the project, eg: OnDraw gets called whenever OnMouseWheel is executed even if I don't explicitly call Invalidate().
So, in the separate drawing function, draw the entire area (not only the visible client area) on the bitmap so that the graphics don't have to be redrawn on the bitmap every time the mouse scrolls. Of course, for this, the size of the bitmap should be large enough, eg. the same as the size of the entire scrollable area.
In the OnDraw, just output the (already finished) drawing on the bitmap to the display(monitor) using BitBlt, but only the part of the bitmap that corresponds to the visible client area using GetClipBox or GetScrollPosition or GetDeviceScrollPosition.
So... in this method, the actual drawing (on the in-memory bitmap though) is done by that custom drawing function, and OnDraw merely outputs some part of the bitmap to the display(monitor).

The CScrollView class handles the scrolling and calls OnDraw() to repaint. It works similarly to CView, but there are a few differences. Basically the CDC is offset by the scroll position. However the rectangle returned by the GetClientRect() function (the window visible area) is in window client coordinates, ie starting from (0,0). So the correct way to use it is draw only the visible area, and this can be achieved by offsetting the client rectangle by the scroll position and pass these values to BitBlt(). No need to call SetViewportOrg() for the memDC, you can simply draw it from its normal origin, (0,0).
Find some of my earlier about this in the links below:
MFC: how to access scroll bar when CScrollView is used?
MFC CScrollView does not clear background

Try modifying your code as shown below:
void CMyScrollView::OnDraw(CDC* pDC)
{
    CDocument* pDoc = GetDocument();
    ASSERT_VALID(pDoc);
    if (!pDoc)
        return;

    CRect rect;
    GetClientRect(&rect);

    CDC memDC;
    memDC.CreateCompatibleDC(pDC);

    CBitmap bitmap;
    bitmap.CreateCompatibleBitmap(pDC, rect.Width(), rect.Height());
    CBitmap* pOldBitmap = memDC.SelectObject(&bitmap);

    // Get the view scroll position and offset the client rect as needed
    CPoint scrollPos = GetScrollPosition();
    rect.OffsetRect(scrollPos);

    // Fill memDC - (rect.left,rect.top) is the starting point, mapped to (0,0) in memDC
    myDrawingFunction(&memDC, rect);

    pDC->BitBlt(scrollPos.x, scrollPos.y, rect.Width(), rect.Height(), &memDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

    memDC.SelectObject(pOldBitmap);
}

Haven't really tested it, just changed it with a text editor, so it may need some fixes. It may need to be modified to handle the case of the view's scrollable area (SetScrollSizes()) being smaller (narrower or shorter) than the visible window area (GetClientRect()).

EDIT:
There are some considerations about the above implementation and its performance. This is not really double-buffering. In OnDraw() you create objects on the fly, and this may involve significant overhead. The code in myDrawingFunction() must be very efficient and particularly should not contain data acquisition/processing/preparation operations, for example opening an image file or getting it from a database and decompressing it. Such operations should be performed in a different part of your code, for example when the image is changed.
Below is some sample code, demonstrating reading of an image initiated by user actions, and properly displaying it in the scroll-view. Loads the whole image and keeps it in memory - it shouldn't be excessively large, it can be several times the screen size though.
    // memDC is a member of CMyScrollView now
    CDC memDC;
    .
    .
    // Called once
    memDC.CreateCompatibleDC(NULL);
    
void CMyScrollView::ChangeImage(LPCTSTR lpFname)
{
    // Load image into memDC
    CImage image;
    if (image.Load(lpFname)!=S_OK)
    {
        // Add some error-handling code
        return;
    }
    
    CSize size(image.GetWidth(), image.Height()); // Get size before Detach()
    HBITMAP hOldBmp = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(memDC.m_hDC, image.Detach());
    if (hOldBmp) DeleteObject(hOldBmp);
    
    // Set the scrollable area size equal to the image size
    SetScrollSizes(MM_TEXT, size);
    Invalidate();
}

void CMyScrollView::OnDraw(CDC* pDC)
{
    CDocument* pDoc = GetDocument();
    ASSERT_VALID(pDoc);
    if (!pDoc)
        return;

    // Get Client Rectangle
    CRect clRect;
    GetClientRect(&clRect);

    // Get the view scroll position and offset the client rect as needed
    CPoint scrollPos = GetScrollPosition();
    clRect.OffsetRect(scrollPos); // pDC is offset by scrollPos

    // Calculate the rectangles to draw
    CSize ts = GetTotalSize();
    CRect imRect(clRect); // Image rectangle to draw - may be smaller than the client area
    if (imRect.right>ts.cx) imRect.right = ts.cx; // We could also use the fancy CRect & operator
    if (imRect.bottom>ts.cy) imRect.bottom = ts.cy;

    // Draw the image - get data from the offset position in memDC
    pDC->BitBlt(scrollPos.x, scrollPos.y, imRect.Width(), imRect.Height(), &memDC, scrollPos.x, scrollPos.y, SRCCOPY);

    // Fill empty areas (if client rect is larger than the image size)
    if (imRect.right<clRect.right)
    {
        CRect rc(clRect);
        rc.left = imRect.right;
        FillRect(pDC->m_hDC, rc, (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(DKGRAY_BRUSH));
    }
    if (imRect.bottom<clRect.bottom)
    {
        CRect rc(clRect);
        rc.top = imRect.bottom;
        FillRect(pDC->m_hDC, rc, (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(DKGRAY_BRUSH));
    }
}

The code above is "logically" the same as drawing the whole image on the whole scrollable area, only it is optimized, drawing only the visible part. You may need to add some typecasts for the GDI objects.

EDIT2:
Yes, the example I posted demonstrates drawing the entire scrollable area in advance, and keeping it in memory so you don't need to do this for every paint request (OnDraw()), which may be triggered by various user actions, like resizing, maximizing/restoring, moving, hiding/unhiding, displaying another window or app on top of it etc, in addition to scrolling. This is a good solution, and you should consider recalculating/redrawing the visible area for every paint request (your initial idea) ONLY if the bitmap is too large to be kept in memory AND the calculation fast enough.
The scrollable area can indeed be smaller than the visible client area, as the former is determined by the size of the data to be displayed, and the the latter by the (parent) "frame" window, for example displaying a small bitmap on a maximized application or MDI client window (the view typically occupies the whole client area of the frame-window). If the scrollable area is smaller than the client, the CScrollView will display no scroll-bar(s).
The example I posted used the CImage class because of the convenience of the Load() method. It can be easily modified to use another data-source, as shown below. No need to use things like viewport or window origin, or clipping boxes.
void CMyScrollView::ChangeImage(LPVOID pMyData)
{
    CSize size = CalcDataSize(pMyData);
    
    // Create a bitmap to hold the data to be drawn
    HDC hDC = GetDC(HWND_DESKTOP);
    HBITMAP hBmp = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hDC, size.cx, size.cy);
    ReleaseDC(HWND_DESKTOP,hDC);
    
    HBITMAP hOldBmp = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(memDC.m_hDC, hBmp);
    if (hOldBmp) DeleteObject(hOldBmp);
    
    // Fill the entire mDC here, eg FillRect(), MoveTo(), LineTo() etc
    DrawWholeClientArea(mDC, pMyData, size);
    
    // Set the scrollable area size equal to the data size
    SetScrollSizes(MM_TEXT, size);
    Invalidate();
}


Thank you but this doesn't work, as expected: 1) The same drawing occurs even after scrolling. Considering your arguments into the BitBlt, this means that the drawing onto the bitmap of the memory DC is the same regardless of the scrolling. 2) rect.OffsetRect(scrollPos) has no point since it's not used. Did you accidentally code it differently than intended?

@starriet주녕차, This code sample draws the same content (no matter the scroll position) because myDrawingFunction() puts the same data in memDC. memDC/bitmap have a size equal to the client rectangle. The function should also take into account the scroll position, to fill memDC properly. Updated the call in the code. Added an alternative example too.

Thanks. Your added example draws the whole image onto the bitmap (I guess the CImage is similar to CBitmap?), so it's different than what my original question was about (drawing only the visible client area, onto the bitmap), but I should reconsider since recalculating&redrawing every time I scroll is inefficient.

Well, I haven't tested it but I think the last part of your code ("Fill empty areas..." part) won't be executed, since the GetTotalSize wouldn't be smaller than GetClientRect (why would someone use scrolling if the whole scrollable area is smaller than the visible client area?). But this isn't important... anyway, thanks again :)

Thanks for the detailed explanations, upvoted! Please let me mark the other answer by myself as an answer not because it's better but merely because it's directly related to the original question and my personal project. Thanks!
